# In PHP how do i know if none of the functions registered using spl_autoload_register have loaded the class?

Tags: php, autoload

In PHP how do i know if none of the functions registered using [spl_autoload_register](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) have loaded the class?

I have many of these functions autoloading from different namespaces (and no namespaces) and it would be nice to be informed (maybe via an exception) if none has been able to load the class.

Comment: If the class can't be loaded, you'll get a fatal error.  Is that enough of an exception for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function that is passed as the first parameter should return true on successfully dealing with the requested class and false on failure. For example if the file does not exist then return false. This way php will throw an exception if none of the classes return true and have dealt with the requested class.

Answer (score 2):

`spl_autoload_register` can take three arguments, and the second argument is a boolean for whether it throws an exception (if it can't register the function). You could pass `true` to that, then catch the exception.

Comment: It only throws an exception if it's unable to register the function, not when the function itself runs.